# My code isn't updating my database

Tags: php, mysql

```html
<?php
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_NAME','shitsandgarbage');
define('DB_PASS','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
if(!$link){
    die('Unable to connect your host: '.mysql_error());
}
$thedb = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link);
if(!$thedb){
    die('Cannot find your database: '.mysql_error());
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sqlemail = "INSERT INTO a (email) VALUES ('$email')";
$sqlpass = "INSERT INTO a (password) VALUES ('$password')";

mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Usename/Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</html>
```

This code snippet isn't updating my database. I'm using XAMPP. What is the problem here exactly?

also my browser is showing the error below
" *mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in D:\XAMPP\Software\htdocs\learning\index.php on line 7*"

Comment: simple: you never executed the queries

Comment: You only save the query in a variable, you also need to run it (`mysql_query(...)`)

Comment: Also - please read about [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: and it's time to step into the 21st century.

Comment: actually i've done it from this tutorial

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wp6Ngpk5XiY&index=2&list=PL530D33D6E548481F

Comment: it's a bad/outdated tutorial. Again, step into the 21st century ;-)

Comment: btw, there's no need for 2 queries, you can insert both at the same time. Again; bad tutorial. Don't store plain text passwords, you WILL get hacked.

Comment: your using the mysql_* functions in php7

Comment: Oh yeah and your site is totally vulnerable to SQL injection attacks if you use that code (will allow anyone to hack your database with ease)

Answer (score -1):

first mysql_* is deprecated in new PHP versions use mysqli or PDO instead; and You does not update your database, use mysql_query for that or mysqli_query.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: if you're going to reference php.net, use an English version http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php